# Wrong coordinates after resizing the map

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I catch a click event on openlayers map and show a popup with featureinfo (if any) with position set as `map.getLonLatFromPixel(new OpenLayers.Pixel(e.xy))`. The user might set the map to show in fullscreen with a button, a little of JS code and some css styling:

```
#geomap_f, #mapbox_f {
    background: white;
    position: fixed !important;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    z-index: 49;
}
```

The problem arises when the user clicks the fullscreened map. The geoserver throws `org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: 979, 8330 not in dimensions of image: 1017, 943` and e.xy object holds some really huge numbers (979, 8330 in this case). I know I need to tell the map or the geoserver (or both) that the mapsize was changed and that I want them to recalculate the relationship between xy and latlon. I've tried using some of OpenLayers.Map methods with no success so far though.
How can it be done? Do I need to resize the map differently? I already call map.updateSize() after resizing, that doesn't seem to influence the coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

For future use: It seems you have to make sure that the contents of the page fit to viewport before resizing a map to fullscreen. This can be easily done with JQuery.hide()/show() methods.